# How to trim multiple cells in a spreadsheet using script?

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting, spreadsheet

I have a column of times with a comment from Forms:

```
'18:00 (pouze v lednu a únoru)
'19:00 (v lednu, únoru i březnu)
'19:00 (v lednu, únoru i březnu)
'18:30 (pouze v lednu a únoru)
```

I want to leave just the times – without the apostrophe on the beginning and the comments, so characters 2–6 should always remain. I am completely new to Scripts and so far I only figured out how to get the column to an array:

```
function cas() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r=ss.getRange("'Odpovědi formuláře 1'!D2:D");
  var vlst=r.getValues();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about following script? Your data is in column D. Data which has an apostrophe at top is not displayed on spreadsheet.

[image]

Time and comment are put in an array from the sheet.

```
function cas() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var vlst = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 4, ss.getLastRow() - 2, 1).getValues(); // retrieving column D from your script
  var array = [];
  for (var i in vlst){
    var time = String(vlst[i]).match(/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/);
    var comment = String(vlst[i]).replace(new RegExp(time[0], "g"), "").match(new RegExp("\\((.+?)\\)"));  
    array.push([time[0], comment[1]]);
  }
}

>>> [[18:00, pouze v lednu a únoru], [19:00, v lednu, únoru i březnu], [19:00, v lednu, únoru i březnu], [18:30, pouze v lednu a únoru]]
```

Answer (score 1):

No script is necessary.  The form data is still in the form as it is entered.  A script editing the data in the column will change this and later edits or re-imports of the data could cause conflicts.  I find it better to use another column for the modified data.  With that in mind:

If your data is in column A, use this formula in the column where you want the modified text:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISTEXT( A2:A),  REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(\d*:\d*)"), ))
```

The ARRAYFORMULA causes the formula to work for every cell in the column.  The IF() is used to apply the formula to the appropriate rows.  The  REGEXEXTRACT() extracts the time from the text.